# is_archive() not working on selected "Posts page"

Tags: posts, archives

I selected a page called "Actualités" in `Dashboard > Settings > Reading > Posts page`.

Wordpress does not use `archive.php` when I load this page, but `index.php`.

So I try to use `is_archive()` in `index.php` but it still returns **false**...

Am I doing something wrong? My sub-goal is to use this page as the archive page so my client can handle it in the menus.

Comment: have you looked at [`is_archive`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive) and the [template hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) in codex?

Comment: I know the template hierachy and archive.php is the last choice for archives if the page is detected as it. My issue is that my page isn't detected as an archive page...

Comment: mh... Actually you're maybe right as Template Hierarchy doesnt mention the default behaviour for WP archives (only for post types), but I hoped that selecting my page as "Posts page" would consider it like an archive page.

Comment: Post page uses index.php or home.php. static front pages uses page templates. `is_archive()` will return false on the post page as this is your homepage

Comment: In the Settings, I selected both: Static home page using a template, Posts page (which is **not** the same).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so... I had this issue, and I couldn't solve it.  It was very weird, but I did come up with a hack. Also, weirdly many other tests also failed.  I was using this in wp_enqueue_scripts specifically, and is_archive() would come back as false when visiting the archive page.  Also, using is_single($page_id) would also come back as false.

What finally worked is to take the archive pages url and parse it.  Mine was /archives.  If I used this, in addition to is_archive, then it will work.  I'll update my answer if someone finds something else.

$is_archives = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/archives') ===0;